# How to email an HTML table through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-email, jspdf

I am writing a program where the user's input is sent to a table, and then the table is to be emailed to a certain email address. I made the table in Javascript using the id of my table. I'm currently trying to use jsPDF to send it to a PDF but not finding much luck. Is this possible, and if so, how can I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While we are happy to help, it is expected for you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a specific problem you are facing in a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```js
var link = document.getElementById("mailto"),
    userInput = document.getElementById("user-input").innerHTML;
   
   
link.setAttribute("mailto", userInput);
```

```html
<a href="#" id="mailto">Send to jsPDF</a>
<table id="user-input">
  Hey...
  <th>Head</th>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 01</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 02</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 03</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```